# invoke filtering manually in dovecot+sieve

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, filtering, sieve

I've configured dovecot with a sieve filtering (also I've configured roundcube, but this does not matter I think).

It's working fine, I've set up some filters. But now I've got a huge unfiltered INBOX folder which I don't want to filter manually.

Is there any way to say: "Hey, sieve! Scan specified folder for specified user and invoke some filters on it!" ?

Sieve as plugin enabled for two protocols: lda and lmtp:

```
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}

protocol lmtp {
  postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com
  mail_plugins = sieve
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To execute your filters on your existent mailbox you can manually run `sieve-filter` from the command line.

To (dry) run the sieve-script `example.sieve` as user `test` on the mailbox `INBOX` use the following command:

```
sieve-filter -v -C -u test /path/to/sieve/example.sieve 'INBOX'
```

Once you like the actions sieve would perform you can execute the script with adding `-e` for execute and `-W` to give sieve write access.

For more information look at the official man page: http://pigeonhole.dovecot.org/doc/man1/sieve-filter.1.html

Comment: sadly, it seems like the `duplicate`-extension does not work in the sieve-filter context.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy :(

```
sudo su user-which-owns-mails
sieve-filter -e -W -u targetuset@domain.com /path/to/sieve/script.sieve INBOX
```